# Using regex to break a string at only the first delimiter

Tags: c#, regex

I am extracting a string which has information given in the following format:

```
Name: ABC Enterprises
Address: 1234 Somewhere Ln
Service Request: They want something done.
```

I need to extract the data label and its associated data, so I was using the regex pattern `(.+):(.+)` with some success (with data labels in Group 1 and associated data in Group 2).  However, as I've expanded the scope, the regex is failing if the "Service Request" has a ':' character in it, as the first group will capture everything from the beginning of the line to the last ':' in the line.  Is there a way to change my regex expression to create the group break for the FIRST ':' instead of the last?  Thanks.

Comment: You could also not use regex.  Just use String.indexOf() to get the location of the first ':' and use String.substring() to break each line apart with the value from String.indexOf().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add anchors (with the multiline option) and use this regex:

```
^([^:]+):[ \t]*(.*)$
```

[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iCxihc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [reluctant/lazy quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy): `(.+?):(.+)`

For better performance, use exclusive matching: `([^:]+):(.+)`

Answer (score 1):

Use an exclusion class to make sure the first group does not have a `':'` in it.

```
([^:]+): (.*)
```